# How to connect to local nodes and modify metadata in the new Helia library?

Tags: javascript, ipfs, nft

I've run into a problem while using the IPFS library. Since the ipfs-http-client has been deprecated and replaced with Helia, I find myself unable to upload pictures to the ipfs-desktop, detect local nodes, and modify the picture's metadata as I used to. I couldn't find any documentation on how to connect to local nodes and modify metadata with Helia. Here's how I used to operate:

```
async function run() {
    const { create } = await import('ipfs-http-client');
    const ipfs = await create();
    const metadata = {
        path: '/',
        content: JSON.stringify({
            name: "My First NFT",
            attributes: [
            {
                "trait_type": "Peace",
                "value": "10" 
            },
            {
                "trait_type": "Love",
                "value": "100"
            },
            {
                "trait_type": "Web3",
                "value": "1000"
            }
            ],
            image: "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmQ2wnwaFJ1w42UTywTWpM8RgiqrWwKFR6AMrpyiHPgi3p",
            description: "So much PLW3!"
        })
    };

    const result = await ipfs.add(metadata);
    console.log(result);

    process.exit(0);
}

run();
```

In this code snippet, I'm creating an instance of ipfs-http-client, then creating an object that contains metadata, and finally adding this object to ipfs.

Now I'm wondering how to achieve the same functionality in the new Helia library. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: IPFS Desktop uses Kubo as a backend, this might be a better drop-in: https://github.com/ipfs/js-kubo-rpc-client